# How to select record from COSMOS DB dependent upon condition

Tags: javascript, sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document in Azure Cosmos DB.

Its Contains :

`{
  "id": "58d56db3b3f730153cab383c",
  "activityDate": "2017-02-11T19:04:18Z",
  ...
  ...
  }`

I Have a requirement to select the document which is older than 3 days only.

for that I have written :
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE

```
function deleteActivitiesBackDate(numberOfDays) {
  var context = getContext();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var link = collection.getSelfLink();
  var response = context.getResponse();

 var targetDate = new Date();

 targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - 3);
 console.log("targetDate is "+targetDate);


  var query = 'SELECT * FROM activities a WHERE a.activityDate < "' + targetDate+ '"';
  var run = collection.queryDocuments(link, query, {}, callback);
  function callback(err, docs) {
    if (err){
        return errorResponse(400, err.message);
    }
    if (docs.length > 0){
        for(var i =0;i<docs.length;i++){
        deleteDoc(docs[i]);
       }
    }else {
        return errorResponse(400, "The document was not found.");
    }
  }

  if (!run) {
      return errorResponse(400, "The document could not be deleted.");
  }

  function deleteDoc(document) {
    var docDeleted = collection.deleteDocument(document._self, function(err, result){
        if (err){
            return errorResponse(400, err.message);
        }
        response.setBody(result);
    });

    if (!docDeleted) {
      return errorResponse(400, "The document could not be deleted.");
    }
  };

  function errorResponse(code,message){
    var errorObj = {};
    errorObj.code = code;
    errorObj.message = message;
    errorObj.date = getDateTime();
    return response.setBody(errorObj);
  } 

  function getDateTime(){
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var dateTime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" +(currentdate.getMonth()+1)+ "-" +     currentdate.getDate()+ " "  +currentdate.getHours()+":"+currentdate.getMinutes()+":"+currentdate.getSeconds();
      return dateTime;
    }
}
```

What can I do to get it fixed?

Comment: What do you mean, the type of `activityDate` is `var`? That's not a type. What does the date property look like, in your documents? Are you storing as epoch? As a formatted string? And what does `targetDate` render as?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the select statement to look use the .toISOString() function like this:

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM activities a WHERE a.activityDate < "' + targetDate.toISOString()+ '"';
```

You current select statement is comparing a string property to a Date() object.

Also, I think you want to change this line:

```
targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - 3);
```

to this:

```
targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - numberOfDays);
```